# "JSON text must be an object or array" error

Tags: php, json

I'm using PHP to connect to an API and register some info using JSON and HTTP POST but it is not going well.

That is what I do:

1. I create a JSON object with the json_encode function:

   ```
   $name = 'Mike';

   $surname = 'Hans';

   $fields = array('name' => json_encode($name), 'surname' => json_encode($surname));
   $postData = json_encode($flds);
   ```
2. Once i have the post data, I just connect to the API with curl and login with oauth, but the API responde says:

> JSON text must be an object or array (but found number, string, true,
>   false or null, use allow_nonref to allow this)

I have checked the allow_nonref in Google, but i could not find anything for PHP, all I have found is for Perl. Does anyone have any solution/advice to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you encode them separately, then encode them together?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to send the entire POST as JSON without nesting calls to `json_encode`, like this:

```
$fields = array('name' => $name, 'surname' => $surname); 
$postData = json_encode( $fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @nickb's answer, please only use one call to `json_encode`,  it's far better at constructing valid json that you and I are, and it's more efficient to boot! (though we are entering the realm of micro-optimisation).

Have you tried taking the output of the `json_encode` and putting it into a validator/formatter such as the one here : http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Also, I think another likely problem could be the headers you are sending? The recieiving server could be strict and enforce that you use the correct 'Content-Type'. Are there any API docs avaliable?